# Unable to raise a case to Salesforce support

Tags: salesforce-support

Please help me how to raise a case to sales force support from my sandbox. I Clicked on Help and Training and it is redirecting me to the login.salesforce.com but not test.salesforce.com. ?

Do i need to enable any of the setting at user level to raise a case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot raise a case from any non-production org, including Developer Edition, Sandboxes, and Scratch Orgs. You will need to log in to your production org and raise a case there. If you have a problem with a specific Sandbox, include the Org Id in your case (there's a field for this purpose), and make sure you Grant Login Access to the Sandbox if necessary.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, and can you please help me in confirming the below: Will SF provide preprod license as well while buying the sandbox licenses. Sorry for irritating you if it's a silly question.

Comment: @user5558 It is my understanding that Salesforce may do so, but you will need to talk to your account executive. You should have been assigned one within a few days of setting up a trial org.